# Disable FileDownload Popup in Screen Scraping (using Webbrowser control)

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, screen-scraping

**Issue:** I am looking at ways to circumvent the FileDownload popup and automatically download the files.

**Implementation Details**
In my Windows Application I am using the Webbrowser component to create a **Screen scraping application**. 
My webBrowser1 is rendered with a view which contains a table (Gridview used in actual page) with a td column(among other td columns) containing an anchor element. Click on the anchor will download the relevant file from SharePoint.
One sample:

```
<td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$TOC$ctl00','DownloadFile$0')">File 1</a></td>
```

To automate the downloads, in my Windows Form I do have a "Download" button in which tried to download the first file in the table (eventually will download all the documents).

My challenge is in downloading the file as it is presented with the FileDowload popup. 
[image]
Is there a way to disable this popup and automatically have the file downloaded in some folder. I understand it is trying to mimic the IE feature.
My code for download is as below:

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("__doPostBack", new string[] { "ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$TOC$ctl00", "DownloadFile$0"});

        }
```

I tried various approaches. One such approach was to use the "urlmon.dll" and use its URLDownloadToFile method. But looks like since the URL is not a normal URL it still keeps giving the FileDownload Popup.

Another approach I tried was to automate the clicks by using "user32.dll" and use the SendKeys to send {TAB} and {Enter} key but I am not able to get the handle for this popup.

```
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", "File Download");
        IntPtr a5 = FindWindow("#32770 (Dialog)", "File Download");
        IntPtr nullptr = (IntPtr)0;
        if (hwnd != nullptr)
        {
            SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            //SendKeys.SendWait("%S");
        }
```

Comment: You are the right path it sounds like. Have you tried using Spy++ in visual studio to see what the Handle looks like and such for that window?  Often times Windows are buried inside of windows and if you aren't referencing the right one, it doesn't work.

Comment: You may think you have the right window, but sometimes the actual correct window is child of the handle you have and such.

Comment: Thank you Alexander, I will give it a try! Please do let me know if you see other good options of achieving the same if any. I also tried the suggestion to disable some properties in IE browser as per link below, but looks like some of these options are no longer available in IE. IE removed as it more of a security concern. 
link: https://superuser.com/questions/246553/how-to-disable-file-download-popup-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

// After the download event start or download button click the file download pop up 
// will appear in webbrowser control. Put following code

```
            Thread now = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); 
                // string nu = GetActiveWindowTitle();
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}"); 
                Thread.Sleep(4000); 
                // now create filename path
                string filepath=@"c:\download\thisdownloadfilehere.pdf"
                SendKeys.SendWait(filepath); 
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");

            });
            now.Start();
```

Comment: addition after string filepath=……. it was missing a semicolon ;